# finding rank of student in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql. I googled  but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

Basically, I need to provide rank to student . The only thing to be considered is explained in given example.
Let we have a table student(id,marks,rank).
Now let the entries be

```
id    marks
1      2
2      2
3      3
4      4 
5      4
6      3
7      3
```

Here the ranks of id's : 4 and 5 should be FIRST.
ranks of id's : 3 , 6  and 7 should be THIRD.
ranks of id's : 1 and 2 should be SIXTH.
What should be the query ?

Comment: Probably ranking should be handled on the application side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate standard competition rankings from a list of scores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901115/generate-standard-competition-rankings-from-a-list-of-scores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing ranking on the application side. If it really needs to be on the MySQL side, you can use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SET @rank = 1, @seq = 1, @last = null;
SELECT *, @rank := if(@last = marks, @rank, @seq) AS rank, @seq := @seq + 1, @last := marks FROM test ORDER BY marks DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a case statement?

```
...
...
CASE
    WHEN marks=4 then rank='First'
    WHEN marks=3 then rank='Third'
    WHEN marks=2 then rank='Sixth'
    ELSE rank='Unk'
END CASE
...
...
```

Edit:  If lanzz is correct, perhaps this useful:

[Generate standard competition rankings from a list of scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901115/generate-standard-competition-rankings-from-a-list-of-scores)

Comment: @lanzz I understand ranking. I am completely sure, howewever, that the OP's question is not clear. I'm not sure he is asking about ranking. I took a chance he was asking the simpler question about data values. We can see. With some more clarity, perhaps we can provide a better answer together.

Comment: It is apparent from the sample data and expected result that the OP is talking exactly about [standard competition ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_.28.221224.22_ranking.29).

Comment: @lanzz  I'm pleased that seems so immediately apparent to you.  Hopefully that will allow you to construct a suitable answer for the OP.  Cheers.